# I have a encrypted java key Encrypting into iOS returns nil

Tags: java, ios, swift, encryption

I am trying to decrypt the following encrypted key in JAVA in iOS.
First Step : I am trying to decode this encoded base 64 key
Second Step : then will decrypt it with private key.

But not able to decode this key getting nil using following decoding function

My encrypted key:

```
EncrytedsecretKey = "bjgZTpZD7DvrjTRXJ6LCA9GpkDnLJLgIVAmFWFXNUVqVWdjXOiOGeRHJx8owW6Pp/a5ECe8CljlwZIAFhRUEPfTks22yntUOhrCUbDzzqYOMiQYfEV/h7/zahl4PV1t4rHXDsQPaf7Rrl8k5jKj0Cf7EaKA4U/pyAjZlvVhMjH8="

if let base64Decoded = NSData(base64Encoded: EncrytedsecretKey, options:   NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        .map({ NSString(data: $0 as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) })
{
    // Convert back to a string
    //println("Decoded:  \(base64Decoded)")
    print(base64Decoded)
}
```

Android Code for Creating Secret Key and encrypting text with Secret Key

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            // 1. generate secret key using AES

            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

            keyGenerator.init(128); // AES is currently available in three key sizes: 128, 192 and 256 bits.The
                                    // design and strength of all key lengths of the AES algorithm are sufficient to
                                    // protect classified information up to the SECRET level

            SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

            // 2. get string which needs to be encrypted

            String text = "<your_string_which_needs_to_be_encrypted_here>";

            // 3. encrypt string using secret key

            byte[] raw = secretKey.getEncoded();

            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));

            String cipherTextString = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))),
                    Base64.DEFAULT);

            System.out.println("cipherTextString : "+cipherTextString);
            
            // 4. get public key

            X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(publicKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT));

            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

            PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);

            // 6. encrypt secret key using public key

            Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");

            cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

            String encryptedSecretKey = Base64.encodeToString(cipher2.doFinal(secretKey.getEncoded()), Base64.DEFAULT);
            
            //System.out.println(encryptedSecretKey);
            System.out.println("encryptedSecretKey : "+encryptedSecretKey);

            // 7. pass cipherTextString (encypted sensitive data) and encryptedSecretKey to
            // your server via your preferred way.

            // Tips:

            // You may use JSON to combine both the strings under 1 object.

            // You may use a volley call to send this data to your server.

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please indicate the key types and how the key was created.

Comment: Hi Maarten,it is created in android and is AES-128 encrypted key